# How to convert a ASP.NET 5 Preview Web Project to Cloud Service

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-cloud-services

I am working in VS2015 and want to add an ASP.NET 5 Preview Web Project to a Cloud Service Web Role. When I click on "Add Web Role Project in Solution" it does not list the new project type, only the old web projects (ASP.NET 4.6).

When you click on the 4.6 project it has a "Convert to Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Project", however this is missing from the 5 project.

How can I associate the Preview project with the Azure Cloud Service web role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported yet. But, if you want, you can create a setup script that installs all the needed components and then you can follow the steps from this post to run it and bootstrap your app: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331425/Running-an-EXE-in-a-WebRole-on-Windows-Azure

Comment: Thanks, will check it out