# A way to publish ASP.NET 5 to Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-cloud-services

A noob's question. I consider using a Cloud Service instance to host a web-app, but my app is based on ASP.NET 5 beta8. Visual Studio tooling doesn't allow me to add an ASP.NET 5 app into a Cloud Service project (which could make it trivial to deploy).

However, it is still just an app. So there must be a general way to put it in, right? Or is it possible only through VS tools?

Comment: Can you not actually create a cloud service project? Or can you create a Cloud Service project but you can't add your asp.net 5 app to it?

Comment: I can create a cloud service project, and then, if there is an MVC 5 (not ASP.NET 5/MVC6) project, it can be added to Cloud Service, but ASP.NET 5 project can't. I think, until it is officially claimed as production ready, it couldn't be a part of a cloud service project. So I'm interested in another way, if there is any, to put it into cloud service (not just an web-app service) on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a duplicate of: [How to convert a ASP.NET 5 Preview Web Project to Cloud Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368546/how-to-convert-a-asp-net-5-preview-web-project-to-cloud-service)

The answer in that thread:

> It's not supported yet. But, if you want, you can create a setup script that installs all the needed components and then you can follow the steps from this post to run it and bootstrap your app: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331425/Running-an-EXE-in-a-WebRole-on-Windows-Azure